# Alternative to join command in bash

Tags: bash, join, command-line

I find it a bit tedious to have to do a sort & then join, and the join command itself is buggy or at best, not intuitive enough to use. Is there any command library with a better implementation of the join command that also does sorting under the hood? All I want is to join smallish CSV files on common columns or by specifying the column index.

Thanks :)

Comment: Post some sample data.

Comment: post sample data, or point out the "bug" you found. and yes, there are other tools can do join, like awk, perl, python...

Comment: Thanks, no all these tools are not intuitive enough - I can write a tool in python. I am asking if there is a join implementation which is done in one step because I want to make my life easier. If there isn't, I will just write my own shell script or pandas script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check out [`q`](https://github.com/harelba/q) with which you can perform [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) on a structured text file ([here](https://github.com/harelba/q/blob/master/EXAMPLES.markdown) you can find some examples).

Comment: looks good. I will try it out and accept the answer if it fits my needs. Thanks!